# Style paper-slider editable input

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to add some customized style to the editable text in `paper-slider`. I know I can style the box of this input by

```
<paper-slider value="0" id="myslider" editable></paper-slider>
```

css

```
#myslider{
    --paper-slider-input: {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        ...
    }
}
```

But how can I style the actual **text**?

I tried

```
#myslider{
    --paper-slider-input: {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        --paper-input-container-input: {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

That is not working. Also, if I want to show a **%** (percentage mark) after the text number, what should I do?

I found [this post](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/issues/150#issuecomment-270511597) as a reference, but the way they tried to hide the arrows after the text did not work on mine. So what is the correct way to hide arrows?

I did actually ask three questions about styling. Any answer with either one or more of them would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I am not aware of any way, how to style `paper-input`. If you look into source code, you can see class `.slider-input` which is the only one applied to `paper-input` and it doesn't support any mixins.

Maybe, there is some way how to propagate some mixin inside custom element and deeper.

Maybe, and i don't much about it, is to use `deep` selector. But I saw somewhere it's deprecated.

About your percentage, i can say only the same.. it doesn't support prefix or suffix. Again, you can look into source code and you will see, that inside `<paper-input>` definition, there isn't `slot` for such things.. Of course that editing source code would solve all these problems, but there have to be some reason why developers didn't do that.

Comment: I appreciate your insights. `deep` selector is deprecated. I found a way to work around it by binding data of the value of slider with some other div for manipulation. But still, thank you.